# Referencing an XML string in an XML Array (Android)

Tags: android

in arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="my_items">
  <item>My item 1</item>
  <item>My item 2</item>
  <item>My item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

in strings.xml

```
<resources>
  <string name="item1">My item 1</string>
  <string name="item2">My item 2</string>
  <string name="item3">My item 3</string>
</resources>
```

I would like to reference the string in the array "My item 1" from strings.xml.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

oh yeah, that is what I meant.  This is how I did it.

```
<string-array name="my_items">
  <item>@string/item1</item>
  <item>@string/item2</item>
  <item>@string/item3</item>
</string-array>
```

It resolved correctly in Android 1.6

Comment: it doesnt work for me if they are in the same xml file...i thought i should add that important note* --using Ubuntu with Eclipse 4.2

Comment: If `@string` isn't recognised, try typing it into the IDE, rather than copying and pasting.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. It *might* be possible to do the reverse: have `@string/item1` in the `<string-array>`.