# Is it possible to access a string-array item in Android?

Tags: android, xml, arrays, layout

snip-code from **values/string.xml**:

```
<array name="categories">
    <item name="today">Today</item>
    <item name="life">Life</item>
    <item name="corner">Corner</item>
    <item name="banks">Banks</item>
    <item name="it">IT</item>
    <item name="fun">Fun</item>
</array>
```

snip-code from **layout/main.xml**:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/today"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:text="@array/categories"
    />
```

Is it possible to assign a label-name to a Button with **id=today** directly from **values/string.xml** using string-array with **name=categories** and specific item, in this case - **today**?

Comment: Ah so you mean android:text="@array/categories[0]" (this is incorrect) but that's what you want right? Tried android:text="@array/categories.today" ?

Comment: That's right, exactly what I meant! But `android:text="@array/categories.today"` doesn't work, other guess?

Answer (score 19):

See the selected answer here: [Android - reference a string in a string array resource with xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml).

According to that answer, have to do something like this:

```
<string name="earth">Earth</string>
<string name="moon">Moon</string>

<string-array name="system">
    <item>@string/earth</item>
    <item>@string/moon</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you would simply do:

```
  <Button ....
  android:text="@string/earth" />
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want to get the value of a single array-item declared in **values/string.xml** file and put that value for a text of a button. `android:text="@array/categories/<item1>"`

Comment: Right, the technique shown above shows how to do that. You just have to change your array values to be structured like the above. Just take another look and try it. Read the answer in the link I posted.

Comment: So, actually it is not possible to be done that way, because it doesn't make any sense to have them both:`<string name="earth">Earth</string>
<string name="moon">Moon</string>` and 
`<string-array name="system">
    <item>@string/earth</item>
    <item>@string/moon</item>
</string-array>`

Comment: The point of having them both mean's you can reference the singular string "today" in your XML file. Then within your code you can reference the array and know that the value you use for <item name="today" will always represent the exact same string as @string/today