# assign button id by retrieving value from string

Tags: android, xml, button, assign

i am a newbie here. My question is as below:

This is my **value/strings.xml** file:

```
<string name="bm">Mengawal</string>
<string name="bi">Managing</string>
 <string name="penan">Penan</string>
<string-array name="menu">
    <item>@string/bm</item>
    <item>@string/bi</item>
    <item>@string/penan</item> 
</string-array>
```

I have my dynamically assign button in my java file. Now, i want to set the button id programmatically from the xml above.
For example,

***the button text is ="Mengawal"
I wana set the button id to become ="bm"***

I saw an example over here, but i cant understand what it actually means. Or is it possible for me to make it like this?
[Is it possible to access a string-array item in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571477/is-it-possible-to-access-a-string-array-item-in-android)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically set resource ids.  Those are compiled into your apk when you build your app.

There is a sort-of workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591768/1105376), where you read in a layout, modify it, save it to the SD card, create an AssetManager for it then you can use it... but it's still not modifying a resource id for an existing resource.