# how to extract id attribute value from string-array

Tags: android, arrays, xml, spinner

I use below code in `my array.xml` file inorder to defining a array:

```
<string-array name="cities_azarbayejanSharghi">
    <item id="15">A</item>
    <item id="36">B</item>
    <item id="140">C</item>
    <item id="95">D</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to access the `id` of each field in the code when it is selected as `spinner`'s `selecteditem`. Is there any ways?

Answer (score 0):

```
TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.your_array);
int resId = ta.getResourceId(arg_positionItem, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be better off referencing other strings, such as the answer [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571477/is-it-possible-to-access-a-string-array-item-in-android):

```
<string name="15">A</string>
<string name="36">B</string>

<string-array name="cities_azarbayejanSharghi">
    <item>@string/15</item>
    <item>@string/36</item>
</string-array>
```