# Assign ressource dynamically vs. big switch case

Tags: android, performance, switch-statement

I have a question regarding performance and best approach for my Android code.

What I need to do is fairly simple, I want to dynamically assign a text value to a string ressource, depending on a int parameter:

For now I am using a big switch case

```
int messagesCategory;
if(extras !=null) {
        messagesCategory = extras.getInt("category");
    }

TextView titleText;
    titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);

switch (messagesCategory) {
    case 1: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageList1); break;
    case 2: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageList2); break;
    case 3: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageList3); break;
    case 4: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageList4); break;

    case ...: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageList...); break;

    case n: titleText.setText(R.string.TitleMessageListn); break;
    default: titleText.setText("a default title");  break;
    }
```

Let's say I have 30 lines in this switch...
It works but for many cases, it looks there is a better way to achieve this.
Unfortunately it does not look possible to assign something dynamic to R.string..

So my first question is: 1) performance wise, in this case, is it a problem to use a big switch for 30 cases or so?
2) what should be the best approach?

Thanks and have a good day

Comment: why not use a string-array resource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple,

```
int[] stringIds = {R.string.TitleMessageList1, R.string.TitleMessageList2,...};

int messagesCategory;
TextView titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
    if(extras !=null) {
            messagesCategory = extras.getInt("category");
            if(messagesCategory  <= n)
            titleText.setText(stringIds[messagesCategory]);
            else  titleText.setText("a default title"); 
 }
```

Now, there is **no switch-case** and comparison,, Basic Java and Android fundamentals make it to easy and short..

As `R.string.XXX` is an `int value` generated in `R.java` file you have to make a just int array of that values and just get value using your `int messagesCategory`. And directly set it to `TextView`..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however on the first line of your code, it looks I would still need to enter manually the 30 Ids... Anyway to avoid that?

Comment: Yes, make a String Array in `array.xml` file  `res/values` directory of your application package. Now directly you can get the array in your code, use `getResource().getStringArray(<array_name>);`

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml

Comment: Srtill not sure what the array is good for when you could pass the R.string.whatever integer right with the Intent, as I suggested in my answer. ;)

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14600678/779408) can be more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
Field f = R.id.class.getField("TitleMessageList" + String.valueOf(messagesCategory));
int val = f.getInt(null);
titleText.setText(val);
```

It is fast without need to load all ids in the memory.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

switch case is the equivalent of `GOTO` in your code, and there is nothing to worry about with performance.

your code is fine, may not be nice but it works and it's efficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think 30 `case` statements don't hurt much except you execute them in a loop, iterating over an array, and such.
2. Why don't you directly use the integers which R.string gives you? Is the mapping really necessary? You could pass the R.string identifiers around. Or else, you could have a lookup in an array if you're really worried about performance.