# Use string array in layout for TextViews' text attribute

Tags: android, arrays, xml

What i need is to define some string array, then use items of that array as values for text attributes in layout for textfields. Something like this:

**arrays.xml:**

```
<string-array name="main_table">
    <item>Mon</item>
    <item>Tue</item>
    <item>Wed</item>
    <item>Thu</item>
    <item>Fri</item>
    <item>Sat</item>
    <item>Sun</item>
</string-array>
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[0]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[1]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[2]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[3]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[4]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[5]" />
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays[6]" />
```

Example above doesn't work as i expected and just shows me textfields with text *@array/weekdays[0]*, *@array/weekdays[1]* and so on. Only if i use array item without index it gets me first array's item for all text fields

```
<TextView style="@style/txt.weekdays"   android:text="@array/weekdays" />
```

I'm **not asking** how to do the trick programmatically, but the way i wrote. I'm not using simple string resources because i need this array in my app anyway in other places, so using string resources will duplicate this array.

Comment: Since you don't want to do the trick programmatically and as you're using static data, why don't you just define this values in strings.xml and call them using @string in your xml layout ? I'm not sure what are you trying to do!

Comment: Actually yes, i can do this, but i need this array anyway in my app. So using string resources will just duplicate this array.

Comment: Define the individual String resources, and create your array from those. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml

Comment: Thanks @Mike, this could be the solution. I even have seen this discussion before but didn't take it in account for this issue...

Answer (score 2):

Accessing `string-array` elements from xml is not mentioned in [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

You can either provide values in code which you don't want.
or use each element as a separate string resource

Comment: Agree, but for some alternative solutions see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/referencing-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml.