# How to load data from a string array from XML layout

Tags: android, arrays, xml

I created a string array resource with several items.
I would like to load these items in my activity_main.xml file.
I tried to load the tag value of a button from a string-array which name is *tagnames*, but it didn't work:

```
android:tag = "@string-array/*tagnames*_2
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you post your string array resource file please?

Comment: Seems like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml) is about the same issue.