# code to retrieve an attribute value from resource file in Android

Tags: android

I have a value resource file(i.e. under values in Android Studio). Below is the code :

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="countrycaptital">
        <item name="NewDelhi">India</item>
        <item name="Japan">Tokiyo</item>
        <item name="US">Washington</item>
<resources>
```

Please guide me to retrieve the country and its capital in my code from this XML data file(in Android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - reference a string in a string array resource with xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
String[] CountryCaptital = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countrycaptital);
```

Then access it as you would any java array. (note the misspelling of "country capital" in your naming...)

EDIT:

Sorry - I didn't realize you were trying to reference the attribute of an `item`. That is not possible. From the docs:

> `<item>`
>
> A string, which can include styling tags. The value can be a
>   reference to another string resource. Must be a child of a
>    element. Beware that you must escape apostrophes and
>   quotation marks. See Formatting and Styling, below, for information
>   about to properly style and format your strings.
>
> No attributes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

You could create two separate string arrays of the same length and use one as the key to the other when creating a `HashMap`, for example.

EDIT:

Two arrays like this:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="capital">
        <item >New Delhi</item>
        <item >Tokyo</item>
        <item >Washington</item>
<resources>
```

and:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="country">
        <item >India</item>
        <item >Japan</item>
        <item >US</item>
<resources>

String[] country = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);   
String[] capital = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.capital);
```

Then create a `HashMap` and use a `for` loop to populate it.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about the misspelling...but this code snippet only returns me the names of countries(i.e. values in the XML file) and not the capitals which are the attributes... :-(

Comment: and sorry I misunderstood your question! Please see me edit.

Comment: Thanks Jim...very helpful...and would be great if you could suggest me any other way of organizing my XML data and then retrieving the attribute value...

Comment: See my edit.. I think that should get you where you need to go.