# How to call R.raw.sound Array from strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, string.xml, raw-file

I want to call this list of raw file from `strings.xml`

```
int[] sound = {

    R.raw.sound1,
    R.raw.sound2,
    R.raw.sound3,
    R.raw.sound4,
    R.raw.sound5,
};
```

How to type in a `strings.xml` and call from code ?

Comment: did u meant getting this string array from Strings.xml ? if so, kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/referencing-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml

Answer (score 0):

> raw folder sound in add to `strings.xml` file array

**`strings.xml`**

```
<string-array name="select_sounds">
     <item>@raw/sound1</item>
     <item>@raw/sound2</item>
     <item>@raw/sound3</item>
     <item>@raw/sound4</item>
     <item>@raw/sound5</item>
 </string-array>
```