# How can I concatenate static strings with XML string resources?

Tags: android, xml, reference, preferences, arrays

I'm trying to combine a static "hard coded" string with one referenced from `strings.xml` for string array items.

The goal is to have a dynamic metrics list where the number is the same for all languages, but the metrics text value may change by language, something like this:

```
<string-array name="interval_labels">
    <item>30 @string/second</item>
    <item>1 @string/minute</item>
    <item>5 @string/minute</item>
    <item>10 @string/minute</item>
    <item>15 @string/minute</item>
    <item>30 @string/minute</item>
    <item>60 @string/minute</item>
</string-array>
```

Right now, if I remove the numbers before the `@string/...` references, it works well (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/android-reference-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml)), but I was wondering whether there is a way to retrieve the referenced string and concatenate it to the "hard coded" one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2865276/1085128 seems to indicate that it is at least almost possible. Possibly even fully possible.

Comment: By defining an XML entity it's possible. I used this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml/24903097#24903097

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, no such syntax is supported by Android resource files.

Comment: if it's so, it's sad, guess I'll have to move the digits to strings.xml as well.

Comment: Using XML entities it is possible to reference the same string multiple times in an Android xml file like strings.xml. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Using XML entities it's possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
  <!ENTITY mintues "minutes">
  <!ENTITY minute "minute">
  <!ENTITY seconds "seconds">
]>

<resources>
  <string-array name="interval_labels">
    <item>30 &seconds;</item>
    <item>1 &minute;/item>
    <item>5 &minutes;</item>
    <item>10 &minutes;</item>
    <item>15 &minutes;</item>
    <item>30 &minutes;</item>
    <item>60 &minutes;</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

I used this answer: [dynamic String using String.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml/24903097#24903097)

Answer (score -1):

There is a way of sort-of getting this effect, by defining the string resource with a place holder and using `String.format()` style overload of `getResourses().getString()` in the code behind:

In string.xml

```
<string name="secs">%1$d seconds</string>
```

In activity_layout.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/secs_label" />
```

In TheActivity.java

```
((TextView)findViewByID(R.id.secs_label)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.secs, 25));
```